# I need to listen if there any changes in the form, make enable/disable SAVE button if there changes or not | Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, subscription

Have issue with listening any changes on a page
there is some information, and even if no changes SAVE button active for click

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.createConfigForm()

        this.configFilterForm.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAll$)).subscribe(value => {
            value
        })
 }
```

```html
<!-- ADD BUTTON -->
            <button
                *ngIf="isUpdate()"
                [disabled]="configFilterForm"
                mat-raised-button
                class="add-config-button"
                (click)="onSave()"
                trackClickSnowplow
                id="config-form_save_button"
            >
                <span>SAVE</span>
            </button>
```

Comment: Please post complete question/code and possibly with a screenshot. Try Stackblitz to get you quick and right assistance.

Comment: I updated part of code, in fact now button disabled but it's doesn't change its state after changing value

Comment: I request to post the entire code which will be helpful for the community to assist you better. Sometimes guesses may lead to wrong answers and time wastage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to the form changes like you are doing now, and every time there is a change, enable the button. Disable the button when you click the button, it will stay disabled until change happens. Something like:

```ts
configFilterForm: FormGroup;
isDisabled = true;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.configFilterForm = this.fb.group({
    input1: ['hello']
  });

  this.configFilterForm.valueChanges.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAll$)
  ).subscribe(value => {
     this.isDisabled = false;
  });
}
```

And button:

```ts
<button [disabled]="isDisabled">Submit</button>
```

**[HERE'S A DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drxmbc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

BTW, I see you are calling some function `*ngIf="isUpdate()"` on your button. Please don't do that, they are called on each change detection and can really slow down your application. Use variables instead!

Comment: Thank you a lot
This realy works, I just added some of code to run it properly=)

Answer (score 2):

Angular provide this functionality out of the box.
All you need to add is form property is: `pristine` or `dirty` and will detect if you have changed something on the form:

> [disabled]="configFilterForm.pristine"

```
<button
   *ngIf="isUpdate()"
   [disabled]="configFilterForm.pristine"
   mat-raised-button
   class="add-config-button"
   (click)="onSave()"
   trackClickSnowplow
   id="config-form_save_button"
   >
    <span>SAVE</span>
   </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML file;

```
<form [formGroup]="formAngular" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="name">

        {{formAngular.controls.name.errors | json}}

        <p 
            *ngIf="formAngular.controls.name.errors?.required && formAngular.controls.name.touched && formSend">
            It is required your name
        </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Send"  />

    <p  *ngIf="formSend && !formAngular.valid">Form is not complete</p>

</form>
```

In your component TS file;

```
  formAngular: FormGroup;

  formSend: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.formSend = false;
    this.formAngular = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(10)
      ])
  }

onSubmit() {
    this.formSend = true;
    console.log("Form value: ", this.formAngular.value);
  }


ngOnInit() {
    const controlName = this.formAngular.controls.name;
    controlName.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(value => {
      console.log("Your changes: ", value);
    });
  }
```